# Получить значение и преобразовать его в число

Tags: jquery

```
var count_audio_post = $('#count_audio_post').text();
```

Получает текст

```
<span id="count_audio_post" style="display:none">0</span>
```

И потом когда я работаю с переменной, то в данном случае вместо **1**, появляется **01**, потом **011** и т.д

```
$('#count_audio_post').text(count_audio_post+1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно просто преобразовать к `int`:

```
var count_audio_post = Number($('#count_audio_post').text());

$('#count_audio_post').text(count_audio_post+1);
```